# Using ddply to summarize multiple variables in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataset with 4 columns,

```
Time                              User.ID Campaign.ID ZIP.Postal.Code
1.495062e+15 AMsySZY9u3XoNZ4qOfmK2JnaXbBg    10852036             H3H
1.495061e+15 AMsySZZE17Pzu6wwv_HkNhVDYSFJ    10852036             L8E
1.495061e+15 AMsySZa8l0q0G9zNCsqGQ9-y5MYi    11181834             G1V
1.495060e+15 AMsySZZOF_CrRXtClA8dna1W-YVg    11181834             T2N
1.495061e+15 AMsySZaGnaf3z8Q7BzFkzxhLD76R    10852036             V7H
1.495061e+15 AMsySZb_uZeGo8NmzdWUBbEL7HEl    11272183             N2C
```

Where each row represents the time at which a user (identified by a unique User.ID) clicks a particular ad (identified by Campaign.ID). There are roughly ~15 or so campaign IDs in this particular dataset.

I would like to organize this dataset into the following form

```
                     User.ID  Click_10852036 Click_11181834 ...
AMsySZY9u3XoNZ4qOfmK2JnaXbBg               1              0
AMsySZb_uZeGo8NmzdWUBbEL7HEl               0              3
```

Where each row represents one user (User.IDs in this table is unique) and each column represents the number of times this users has clicked on that particular ad.

I know I can do this using ddply by

```
table_c = ddply(data, .(User.ID), summarize,
    click_10852036 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10852036'),
    click_9349165 = sum(Campaign.ID == '9349165'),
    click_11272183 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11272183'),
    click_11266100 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11266100'),
    click_11181834 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11181834'),
    click_10950859 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10950859'),
    click_11224930 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11224930'),
    click_11224368 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11224368'),
    click_11029515 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11029515'),
    click_9123038 = sum(Campaign.ID == '9123038'),
    click_10748814 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10748814'),
    click_10792241 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10792241'),
    click_11152245 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11152245'),
    click_10675627 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10675627'),
    click_8532119 = sum(Campaign.ID == '8532119'),
    click_10811017 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10811017'),
    click_10694683 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10694683'),
    click_11463760 = sum(Campaign.ID == '11463760'),
    click_9676864 = sum(Campaign.ID == '9676864'),
    click_10847880 = sum(Campaign.ID == '10847880'))
```

Is there a way of summarizing this table without explicitly writing out all of the column headers?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need is to use `Campaign.ID` also in the grouping variable and then `spread` it 'wide' format

Comment: reproducible examples help. look at `data.table::dcast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
library(reshape2)
df$Count=1
df1=as.data.frame(acast(df, User.ID~Campaign.ID,value.var="Count"))
names(df1)=paste0('Click_',names(df1))
#Change the NA to 0
df1[is.na(df1)]=0

> df1
                             Click_10852036 Click_11181834 Click_11272183
AMsySZa8l0q0G9zNCsqGQ9-y5MYi              0              1              0
AMsySZaGnaf3z8Q7BzFkzxhLD76R              1              0              0
AMsySZb_uZeGo8NmzdWUBbEL7HEl              0              0              1
AMsySZY9u3XoNZ4qOfmK2JnaXbBg              1              0              0
AMsySZZE17Pzu6wwv_HkNhVDYSFJ              1              0              0
AMsySZZOF_CrRXtClA8dna1W-YVg              0              1              0
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.